# Java Scanner returning null but already filtered out

Tags: java, lexer

```
public void process() throws InputMismatchException {
    //System.out.println(code);



    if(sc.findInLine("JP++") == null || sc.findInLine("START") == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Program has to start with 'JP++ _NAME_ START' ");



    }
    sc.nextLine();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
            if (sc.findInLine(Pattern.compile("JP......")) != "JP++ END" ){
                Scanner r = sc;
                if(!r.hasNextLine() || r.findInLine(Pattern.compile(".")) == null){
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

            }

    }

}
```

This code is a part of a lexer I am currently working on. I already filtered out to prevent the scanner from outputting null and it still output:

```
hello 
world
null
```

my input: `"   JP++ HELLO WORLD START \n hello \n world\n JP++ END"`

How can I solve this thx

Comment: `... != "JP++ END"` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this code :

```
    String input = "   JP++ HELLO WORLD START \n hello \n world\n JP++ END";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);

    if(sc.findInLine("JP++") == null || sc.findInLine("START") == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Program has to start with 'JP++ _NAME_ START' ");
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
            if (sc.findInLine(Pattern.compile("JP......")) != "JP++ END" )  {
                Scanner r = sc;
                if(!r.hasNextLine() || r.findInLine(Pattern.compile(".")) == null){
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
    }
```

Which is literally a copy and paste of your code except for the input (which I also literally copied from your post) and Scanner declaration. It prints out

> hello
>   world

with no null. Whatever your issue is it is elsewhere.

Edit : As @Pshemo mentions you are also comparing your string wrong. Use .equals()